# Problem with plotting data

Tags: plotting, data

I am attempting to plot a large amount of data that I have imported from a file — dimensions {400, 2}. Both `ListPlot` and `Plot` return empty plots showing no data. When evaluating these function, Mathematica computes for a while though, as if it were processing something.

```
datalist = 
  {{650.`, "0.3991552293"}, {"649.5", "0.4087565541"}, ..., {450.`, "0.7589305043"}}
```

Both

```
Plot[datalist, {x, 500, 600}]
```

and

```
ListPlot[datalist]
```

fail to show the data.

Can anybody help?

Comment: your `datalist` should have numeric entries (it has strings). Try `newlist = datalist  /. 
   s_String :> ToExpression[s];ListPlot[datalist]`

Comment: The strings are the problem. Look up `ToExpression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points you should be aware of (some of which were already mentioned in comments to your question).

- Your data contains strings. They must be converted to numbers.
- `Plot` is for plotting symbolic expressions. It won't work for data pairs.

So this is how to proceed:

```
rawData =
  {{650.`, "0.3991552293"}, {"649.5", "0.4087565541"}, {450.`, "0.7589305043"}};
data = rawData // ToExpression;
ListPlot[data]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you all! Makes total sense.

Comment: @Student. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.